# PHP is not able to invoke a command (Prokka) usning shell file not from C file

Tags: php, html, c, shell, web

Prokka is a tool used to annotate bacterial genomes and can be installed and access using the command line in the local system or server.

So, I have downloaded Prokka using Git clone (`git clone https://github.com/tseemann/prokka.git`) and complied it on the CentOS (7) server along with all the dependencies with the latest version (NCBI-BLAST 2.10.1, hmmer 3.3, gnu Parallel).

In order to make a prediction server, I have created a webpage using PHP, and in that PHP file, I'm taking input from the user and passing that input to a shell file, and trying to execute that shell file using the shell_exec() function.
Here `$fileName and $fn` are the input from taken from the webpage.

```
$output = shell_exec("./path/to/shell/file/invoke.sh  $script_path/$fileName  $fn"); 
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

invoke.sh file:

```
input_genome="$1";
prefix_genome="$2";
/path/to/prokka/bin/prokka $input_genome --outdir ./results/"$prefix_genome"  --prefix $prefix_genome --locustag $prefix_genome --cpus 8 --kingdom Bacteria
```

Now, if I'm invoking Prokka (`/path/to/prokka/bin/prokka`) directly from the command line it's working fine and create all the files which ideally it should create. Moreover, if I'm running the shell script (`invoke.sh`) to invoke the  Prokka (`/path/to/prokka/bin/prokka`) it's again working fine and generate all the files.
Expected and actual output files:

```
seq.faa
seq.err
seq.fna
seq.txt
seq.ffn
seq.gff
seq.tsv
seq.fsa
seq.gbk
seq.tbl
seq.log
seq.sqn
```

But the problem is while I'm running the PHP file from the web-browser as mentioned above to run the shell file (invoke.sh) it is running, but the Prokka command is not running properly inside the shell file and therefore not generating all of the output files.

I checked the error_log it showed me this:

```
[23:43:57] Will use blast to search against /home/group01/html/csspred/prokka/db/kingdom/Bacteria/sprot with 8 CPUs
[23:43:57] Running: cat \/home\/group01\/html\/csspred\/results\/01\-Nov\-23_43_779958414\/seq\/seq\.sprot\.tmp\.18401\.faa | parallel --gnu --plain -j 8 --block 3279 --recstart '>' --pipe blastp -query - -db /home/group01/html/csspred/prokka/db/kingdom/Bacteria/sprot -evalue 1e-09 -qcov_hsp_perc 80 -num_threads 1 -num_descriptions 1 -num_alignments 1 -seg no > \/home\/group01\/html\/csspred\/results\/01\-Nov\-23_43_779958414\/seq\/seq\.sprot\.tmp\.18401\.blast 2> /dev/null
[23:44:00] Could not run command: cat \/home\/group01\/html\/csspred\/results\/01\-Nov\-23_43_779958414\/seq\/seq\.sprot\.tmp\.18401\.faa | parallel --gnu --plain -j 8 --block 3279 --recstart '>' --pipe blastp -query - -db /home/group01/html/csspred/prokka/db/kingdom/Bacteria/sprot -evalue 1e-09 -qcov_hsp_perc 80 -num_threads 1 -num_descriptions 1 -num_alignments 1 -seg no > \/home\/group01\/html\/csspred\/results\/01\-Nov\-23_43_779958414\/seq\/seq\.sprot\.tmp\.18401\.blast 2> /dev/null
```

and generated only four files :

```
seq.HAMAP.hmm.tmp.12617.faa
seq.HAMAP.hmm.tmp.12617.hmmer3
seq.fna
seq.log
```

I even used a C file to invoke the execute a shell file which ultimately invokes the Prokka command but again the problem remained the same.

PHP: `$output = shell_exec("./invoke.out  $script_path/$fileName  $fn");`

C:

```
`int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                         
char command[1000];                                                                                                                                                    
sprintf(command, "%s %s %s", "sh /home/group01/html/csspred/scripts/CSS_pred_new_additions/prokka_test.sh", argv[1], argv[2]);                                         
system(command);
}`
```

**What is the problem and how to solve this? I just wanted to execute my invoke.sh or invoke.out so that at the backend my Prokka command will be able to run correctly and gives me all expected output files.**